# How does the checkbox know its association with the textview

Tags: android, checkbox

I am coding a checklist on android, following an example from a textbook.
The ListActivity consists of a listview (R.layout.PCheckList) where each row has a checkbox and a textview locked inside a horizontal layout (R.layout.lchecklist). 
There is a line of the code which I totally do NOT understand
The code is below, and the i've highlighted the line

```
public class PChecklist extends ListActivity {

    TextView selection;
    String[] tasks={"Do Laundry",
            "Wash Dishes",
            "Make the bed",
            "Study",
            "Buy Groceries",
            "Mow the lawn",
            "Shave",
            "Iron Clothes",
            "Breathe periodically"};

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.pchecklist);

        this.selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection2);


        ArrayList<DailyTask> dailyTaskListModel = new ArrayList<DailyTask>();
        for(String t:tasks)
        {
            dailyTaskListModel.add(new DailyTask(t));
        }

        this.setListAdapter(new CheckListAdapter(this,dailyTaskListModel));
    }

    private DailyTask getTaskAt(int position)
    {
        return ((CheckListAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        this.selection.setText(String.format("Selection: %s", getTaskAt(position).toString()));
    }

    class DailyTask
    {
        String task;
        boolean isCompleted = false;

        DailyTask(String task)
        {
            this.task = task;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            if(this.isCompleted)
                return (task.toUpperCase());
            else return (task);
        }
    }

    class CheckListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DailyTask>
    {
        Activity activity;

        CheckListAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<DailyTask> taskList)
        {
            super(context, R.layout.lchecklist,taskList);

            this.activity = context;
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View recycledView = convertView;
            CheckListViewAccessor checkListViewAccessor=null;
            CheckBox checkbox;

            if(recycledView==null)
            {
                //if there is no view, we have to make one by inflating a layout.
                LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
                recycledView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lchecklist, null,false);

                checkListViewAccessor = new CheckListViewAccessor(recycledView);
                recycledView.setTag(recycledView);
                checkbox = checkListViewAccessor.getCheckBox();

                CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkStateChangedListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean isChecked) {
                        //When the check button is pressed, we want two things to happen.
                        //1. Update the model.
                            //for some reason we have to do this.
                            int positionOfCheckedItem = (Integer) cb.getTag();

                            DailyTask task = getTaskAt(positionOfCheckedItem);
                            task.isCompleted = isChecked;

                        //2. Change the String in the row to upper case.
                            cb.setText(task.toString());
                    }
                };

                checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkStateChangedListener);

            }else//if recycledView is not null, then we don't need to add a listener, we just need to get access to the UI components
            {
                checkListViewAccessor = (CheckListViewAccessor) recycledView.getTag();
                checkbox = checkListViewAccessor.getCheckBox();
            }

            DailyTask task = getTaskAt(position);
            checkbox.setTag(new Integer(position));
            **checkbox.setText(task.toString());
                    //^This line I don't get.**
            checkbox.setChecked(task.isCompleted);


            return (recycledView);
        }

    }

    class CheckListViewAccessor
    {
        View checkListView;
        CheckBox checkbox=null;

        CheckListViewAccessor(View checkListView)
        {
            this.checkListView = checkListView;
        }

        CheckBox getCheckBox()
        {
            if(checkbox==null)
                this.checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            return (checkbox);
        }
    }
}
```

In the line indicated, how does the checkbox know which TextView's text to change? When was this relationship established?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no associated `TextView` with `CheckBox`. Because `CheckBox` is a `TextView`. Take a look at hierarchy [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html):

```
ava.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.widget.TextView
           ↳    android.widget.Button
               ↳    android.widget.CompoundButton
                   ↳    android.widget.CheckBox
```

In other words `CheckBox` is a `TextView` with additional state management for `checked` and `unchecked`. (In fact `CompoundButton` is responsible for state management, but those are details).

Answer (score 0):

The relationship is established by the adapter. For each list element, the "checkbox" object corresponds to the actual list element's checkbox. This means it's very easy to modify the Views of the list elements, and in extension it's very tricky to alter another element from within a particular element in the `getView()`.

You might think of it this way; in the adapter - for every `getView()` - the current element will be seen as "local variables" from your point of view. You won´t have to bother about all global elements at this time.